# MYSQL- Control Flow Functions

Tags: mysql

Been working on this for a couple of hours now and I wonder if there is a recommended solution for this in SQL or if I am better off putting this in my application logic instead of the database. I'd prefer the former.

```
CREATE TABLE `rate_info` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`rate_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`rate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`vendor` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`product` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`days_to_pickup` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`state` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`country` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=787 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

I need come up with the best estimate for average rate of each product and vendor combination, given a city, state & country. Each vendor can have a different number of products. Also, the number of  vendors in each city can be different. The logic needs to be

1. Return data for records matching city, state and country, if a match is found.
2. If a match is not found, try to find results based on state & country.
3. If that doesn't return anything either, find results based on country only
4. Last resort, use all records to come up with the average rate of each product, vendor combination
5. There is additional logic for other columns, but they all follow the same pattern as location.

The first query will be something like

```
select avg(rate) rate, vendor, product from rate_info
where city = 'Boston'
and state = 'MA'
and country = 'United States'
and rate_type = 'REGULAR'
and days_to_pickup >= 4
group by vendor, product
```

I have been playing around with COALESCE, CASE, IFNULL, but can't get the queries to work. I can do it in the application layer, but I'd have to make multiple calls to the database as there is high likelihood that the first case will not be met.

The ideal solution would be something like

```
COALESCE(select_city_state_cntr, select_state_cntry, select_cntry);
```

Let me know if something is missing and I'll add more details as required.

Thank you

Comment: @ First question here, please read what to do [when you get answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: It's complicated now; Strange that you're not looking for average rate of single (product, vendor) pair. As record count can vary for all possible products in a region, single query will be difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you right results (if I got you requirements right), though its not efficient, since it calculates all options even in case exect city is found:

```
SELECT 
  (city = 'Boston') * rate AS exactCityData, 
  SUM((city != 'Boston' AND state = 'MA') * rate) AS wholeStateData, 
  SUM((city != 'Boston' AND state != 'MA' AND country = 'United States') * rate) AS wholeCountryData
WHERE country = 'United States'
GROUP BY vendor, product;
```

For state average, you cannot use AVG, since query matches all rows (in country), thus the query should be like that:

```
SELECT 
  (city = 'Boston') * rate AS exactCityData, 
  SUM((state = 'MA') * rate) / SUM(state = 'MA') AS wholeStateData, 
  AVG(rate) AS wholeCountryData
WHERE country = 'United States'
GROUP BY vendor, product;
```

Now for firth "last resort" option, drop country requirement, and replace `AVG(rate) AS wholeCountryData` part with `SUM((country = 'United States') * rate) / SUM(country = 'United States')  AS wholeCountryData`

Comment: interesting; will check tomorrow morning. Nice

Comment: This is pretty good! I changed the query a little bit as I need data for Boston included in data for state='MA' and so on. `SELECT vendor, product, (city = 'Boston' and state = 'MA') * rate AS exactCityData,
SUM((state = 'MA') * rate) AS wholeStateData, 
SUM((country = 'United States') * rate) AS wholeCountryData
from rate_info
GROUP BY vendor, product;` One problem that I am still struggling with is that I need the average of the rates, not sum. However, when I replace SUM with AVG, the average rate seems incorrect.

Comment: It seems when I change SUM to AVG, the average is calculated using the total number of rows rather than the matching ones. For data : `Boston  MA 115
Nashua  MA 50
Cambridge MA 10
Edison  NJ 70 `                                  the sum is calculated correctly, but the average for state shows 43.75 and for country - 61.2. This is state total = 175/4 (total number of rows), instead of 175/3 (matching rows for the state).

Comment: @Bhardwaj, this makes sense, since the query matches all rows in the country. I updated the answer so it calculates only the "right" rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution.  Query all three ways, and use LIMIT to take the first one that matches.

```
SELECT * FROM (
 (SELECT SUM(population) AS population, city, state, country
  FROM POPULATION
  WHERE (city, state, country) = (?, ?, ?))
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT SUM(population), NULL, state, country
  FROM POPULATION
  WHERE (state, country) = (?, ?))
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT SUM(population), NULL, NULL, country
  FROM POPULATION
  WHERE (country) = (?))) AS t
WHERE t.population IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Why does it return all null for third condition? `If that doesn't return anything either, return population based on country only`

Comment: The third condition only returns null for city and state.

Comment: try all three conditions with some data you'll get what I mean.

Comment: Aha!  It's because an aggregate query using SUM() always returns 1 row, even if there were no rows matched by the WHERE clause.

Comment: @DoSparKot, I've fixed the query above after testing it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `population` (
  `city` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `population` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and a select query:

```
SELECT city, state, country, population
  FROM population
 WHERE country = '<country>' AND state = '<state>' AND city = '<city>'
UNION
SELECT null, state, country, sum(population)
  FROM population
 WHERE country = '<country>' AND state = '<state>'
 GROUP BY state
UNION
SELECT null, null, country, sum(population)
  FROM population
 WHERE country = '<country>'
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns a lot of data and I then have to filter out the extra records in my code. Keep in mind that the table structure I've mentioned is a trimmed down version of the actual problem. There are many additional columns apart from population that will be fetched. If I could do this in COALESCE, it would be perfect - COALESCE(query_city_state_cntry, query_state_cntry, query_cntry) and it will return the first not null/empty result. Anything on these lines possible?

Comment: Specify the complete table schema.

Comment: Sorry, first time here and a bit lost. I've updated the question with additional details.